# Galería con item que carga segunda página con #

Tags: php

Tengo una duda en como puede estar funcionando este código que muestro. En el se muestra comentadas las partes que a continuación explico: la página muestra una galería con items que cargan imágenes y textos. Cada imagen tiene a su vez un enlace

```
<a href="#"><img src="img/banner/<?php echo $row->url_image;?>" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                        <div class="overlay">
                          <div class="inner">
                            <h3 class="h4 reference-title"><?php echo $row->titulo;?></h3>
                            <p><?php echo $row->descripcion_corta;?></p>
                          </div>
                        </div></a>
```

que en apariencia no tiene enlace ya que el href apunta a # . Pero en realidad está apuntando a segunda parte comentada en el código que es una nueva página (aunque no lo parezca ya que está en el mismo archivo) donde se muestra ampliada la información de cada item con imagen ampliada, texto ampliado y un enlace que se cargan por bd. 
Mi pregunta es como está realizándose el enlace a esta nueva página con información ampliada. No veo que haya alguna relación entre enlace con # y la zona que se corresponde con la "página de información ampliada". Lo único que noto diferente y que sospecho pueda ser parte de esta carga es un `<div data-images=` que pueda tener algo que ver. 
No sé, si alguien sabe como funciona le agradezco su ayuda.

```
<div id="references-masonry" data-animate="fadeInUp">
        <div class="row">
        <?php
            $sql_banner_top=mysqli_query($con,"select * from portafolio where estado=1 order by orden ");
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_object($sql_banner_top)){
                ?>
             <div data-category="webdesign" class="reference-item col-lg-4 col-md-6">
              <!--Esta zona muestra la galeria que contiene items. Cada item enlaza a una pagina con imagen ampliada, descripcion,etc-->
                <div class="reference"><a href="#"><img src="img/banner/<?php echo $row->url_image;?>" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                    <div class="overlay">
                      <div class="inner">
                        <h3 class="h4 reference-title"><?php echo $row->titulo;?></h3>
                        <p><?php echo $row->descripcion_corta;?></p>
                      </div>
                    </div></a>
                    <!--Esta zona es la que carga cada item de la galeria con su imagen ampliada, descripcion, enlace pero... ¿COMO SE CARGA?-->
                  <div data-images="img/banner/<?php echo $row->url_image;?>" class="sr-only reference-description">
                    <p><?php echo $row->descripcion;?></p>

                    <p class="buttons text-center"><a href="<?php echo $row->url_web;?>" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> Visitas Sitio Web</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Añado esta nueva información que no había visto. Son unas funciones que venían enlazadas y que no había localizado. Seguro que ahora cobrará más sentido para quién pueda entender todo:

```
$('.reference a').on('click', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var title = $(this).find('.reference-title').text(),
        description = $(this).siblings('.reference-description').html();

    $('#detail-title').text(title);
    $('#detail-content').html(description);

    var images = $(this).siblings('.reference-description').data('images').split(',');
    if (images.length > 0) {
        sliderContent = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
            sliderContent = sliderContent + '<div class="item"><img src=' + images[i] + ' alt="" class="img-fluid"></div>';
        }
    } else {
        sliderContent = '';
    }

    openReference(sliderContent);

});

function openReference(sliderContent) {
    $('#detail').slideDown();
    $('#references-masonry').slideUp();


    if (sliderContent !== '') {

        var slider = $('#detail-slider');

        if (slider.hasClass('owl-loaded')) {
            slider.trigger('replace.owl.carousel', sliderContent);
        } else {
            slider.html(sliderContent);
            slider.owlCarousel({
                nav: false,
                dots: true,
                items: 1
            });

        }
    }
}


function closeReference() {
    $('#references-masonry').slideDown();
    $('#detail').slideUp();
}

$('#filter button, #detail .close').on('click', function () {
    closeReference();
});
```

Ahora veo que al pulsar en cualquier enlace con clase references desencadena una serie de acciones. Tengo ahora la duda sobre que hace exactamente este codigo:

```
var images = $(this).siblings('.reference-description').data('images').split(',');
```

¿Que es .data('images') ?